# Can I use Hadoop to speed up a slow SQL stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, performance, hadoop, bigdata

### The problem:

I have 2 SQL Server databases from 2 different applications. They describe different aspects of industrial machines: one is about "how many consumables were spent per order", the other is about "how many good/bad production items were produced per operator". Sometimes many operators are working on 1 order one after another, sometimes one operator is working on multiple small orders, and there is no connection Order-Operator in the database.

I want to have united fact table, where for every `timestamp` I know `MachineID`, `OrderID` and `OperatorID`. If a `timestamp` exists in DB1, then the record will have numeric measures from it (Consumables); if it exists in DB2, then it will have numeric measures from DB2 (good/bad production items). If it exists in both databases, then it have all numeric measures. A simple `UNION ALL` is not enough, because I want to have `MachineID`, `OrderID` and `OperatorID` for every record.

I created a T-SQL stored procedure to make `FULL JOIN` by timestamp and MachineID. But on large data sets (multiple machines, multiple customers) it becomes very slow. Both applications support editing history, so I need to merge full history from both databases at every nightly load.

To speed up the process, I would like to put calculations into multiple parallel threads, separated by `Customer`, `MachineID`, and `Year`.

I tried to do it by using SQL Server stored procedures, running in parallel by SQL Agent with different parameters, but I found that it didn't help the performance. Instead it created multiple deadlocks when updating staging and final tables.

I am looking for an alternative way to resolve this problem, but **I don't know what is the right tool**. Can Hadoop or similar parallel processing tool help with this task?

I am looking for solution with minimal cost, because it is needed for just one specific task. For everything else, SQL Server and PowerBI reporting are working just fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop seems hard to justify in this use case, given limited scope. The thing about Hadoop is that it scales well not only due to parallel processing but thanks to parallel IO, when data is distributed across multiple servers/storage media. Unless you happy to copy all data to HDFS distributed among multiple nodes, it likely will not help much. If you want to spin up a Hadoop cluster and run multiple jobs querying single SQL server, it'll likely end up badly for the later.

Have you considered optimizations which will allow you to limit the amount of data you processing nightly?

E.g. what is 'timestamp' field? Does it reflect last update time? Can you use it to filter rows which haven't been updated since the previous run?

Even if the 'timestamp' is not the time of last updates, can you add an "updateTime" field and triggers on updates which will populate the field, so you don't need to import rows which have not changed since the previous run? If you build an index on the field, then, if the number of updates during the day is not high relative to total table size, a query with a filter on such field will hit the index, and fetching of incremental changes should be fast.

Another thing to consider - are those DBs running on the same node/SQL server? Access to remote DBs is slow, so if that's the case, think about how to fix this first.